# In Sequelize, update all rows where a JSONB object's array contains a given string

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb, sequelize-typescript

I am using PostgreSQL. I have a table `users` with a `JSONB` column `preferences`. It can take a shape like so:

```
{
  pets: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Goldfish'],
  cars: ['Sedan', 'Van'],
  // Other keys; irrelevant

}
```

In TypeScript, I have a function like so:

```
function removePetFromAllUsers(pet: string) {
  // Sequelize query to go here
}
```

I need a sequelize query to update all rows in the `users` table whose `pets` contain the string in the parameter. For instance, any user with "Dog" as a preferred pet should have it removed in their `preferences.pets` array.

How do I write this query?

I am expecting all rows from which `preferences.pets` contain the string `pet` to be updated such that `preferences.pets` do not contain the string `pet` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query like so:

```
await users.update(
    {
      preferences: literal(
        `jsonb_set(preferences, '{pets}', (preferences->'pets') - 'Dog')`,
      ),
    },
    {
      where: {
          { preferences: { pets: { [Op.contains]: `["Dog"]` } } },
      }
    },
  );
```

Here you can use [`jsonb_set()` and the delete operator `-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html).